# Javascript - how to "Request Query String" from Url.Action link to retrieve parameter value?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I've written the following codes on page 1 :

```
location.href = '@Url.Action("Page2", "Home")?MyDetail=' + age;
```

Upon clicking "Submit" button, it'll go to Page2 and the link bar will display:

"http://localhost:1234/Home/Page2?MyDetail=20"

Question is, on page 2 of my view level, how can I "request query string" to get the parameter value (i.e. age) from the link by using javascript?

Other questions I've searched used certain regular expressions which I didn't understand but I was wondering if there is another method. If regular expressions need to be used, I'd appreciate if someone could explain how's it working.

Comment: asp.net: To get a querystring you can use the `Request.Querystring property`:

`Request.Querystring("parameter1")` and for javascript you could use this:[/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: @KevinKloet Thanks for the comment! Yes, Request.Querystring is the one I know of, but I'm stuck on how to use it the javascript way. The link provided is the one I managed to search for but I don't understand how it is used.

Comment: what part of it do you not understand? the regex? the returns?

Comment: @KevinKloet Like, why the reply (name.replace), what those that they are replacing means, about the regex and what are the returns based on? The whole thing actually..

Comment: pretty hard to read
`function getParameterByName(name, url){ if (!url){ /*if url param is passed*/ url = window.location.href; /*get current url*/ } name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&"); /*replace any escaped characters*/ var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"), results = regex.exec(url);  /*name after ? or &,match anything that is not a & or #, or match & or # or $.*/ if (!results) return null; /*if result is undefined */if (!results[2]) return ''; /*if results[2] is undefined*/ return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " ")); //decode and replace +}`

Answer (score 3):

In C#:

```
string parameter = Request.QueryString["MyDetail"].ToString();
```

In Javascript:

```
var url = window.location.href; 
var split = url.split("MyDetail="); 
var currentURL = split[1];
```

Comment: Is there a way for me to use javascript instead?

Comment: u can use jquery...I will give u one example

Comment: var url = window.location.href; 

 var split = url.split("MyDetail="); var currentURL = split[1];

Comment: @shajeerpuzhakkal your answer has no jQuery in it... that is pure JavaScript.

Comment: @shajeerpuzhakkal could you explain what the url.split("MyDetail=") does? And what the split[1] represents / what currentURL would contain?

Comment: `var split = url.split(MyDetail=)` splits the string url at that point, `split[0]` equals the part before the match of the `MyDetail=` and `split[1]` matches the first part after the `MyDetail=` in case you have multiple times `MyDetail=` in the url string you could specify which one you want to get. read more here: [javascript split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: Here our requirement is to get the ID.So I splite the URL "http://localhost:1234/Home/Page2?MyDetail=20"" with MyDetail.If I am spliting with any other thing instead of MyDetail (ex:Splitting with '/' then array size will increase.).If you have more doubt try it in your machine.